# XCode Linking to a storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I had a XIB file and I would like it like so:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

 switch (indexPath.row)
        {

            case 0:
                LHPurchaseOrder *purchaseOrderController = [[LHPurchaseOrder alloc]initWithNibName:@"LHPurchaseOrder" bundle:nil];
                purchaseOrderController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
                [self presentViewController:purchaseOrderController animated:YES completion:nil];
                break;
        }


}
```

Now I need to use a split view controller (which apparently you can only use in a storyboard) So I created a storyboard for this one view. Now I need to know how to link it from my table view to storyboard instead of my XIB File. Is this possible? I looked into Storyboard Segue Tutorial, but I found it confusing and I think its not what I am looking for. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Add answer, any feedback?

Answer (score 0):

```
LHPurchaseOrder *vc= [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LHPurchaseOrder"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```